# Play Framework Public Assets "WEB Handler Not Found"

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0

The first route below works, but the second doesn't.  I want to serve a onepage angular/sockets app from my /public directory, but when I try via 2 below, I get a "WEB Handler Not Found error.

1/
GET        /assets/*file                    controllers.cm_admin.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)

2/
GET        /*file               controllers.cm_admin.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)

Answer (score 0):

Just worked it out.

I had the following statement in my app/Global:

```
case 'admin' => admin.Routes.routes.lift(request)
```

and changed it to:

```
case _ => admin.Routes.routes.lift(request)
```